# "Square" + "-er" suffix: Denoting a person belonging to a company called "Square"

Tags: demonyms

According to [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/-er), the `-er` suffix could be used to *denote a person belonging to a specified group* (e.g. *New Yorker* for New York).

Suppose now that I work for a company called "Square". That is, I "belong" to a group of other people, the Square company. Is it correct to say that I am a *Squarer*?

Comment: You would have to ask the "Square" company that.

Comment: I'd go with the _squareman_ 

Comment: Hmm, [Googler](http://www.google.com/about/careers/lifeatgoogle/) for Google is fine. Googleman is a bit weird, isn't it? 

@user3169 Unfortunately I can't ask them. :-/

Comment: What about people that work for a company called "Toss"?

Answer (score 1):

You are making up a word, so there is no universally correct way to do this. "Squarer" follows the -er rule, but it sounds odd, and the fact that "square" is a common word makes it confusing for outsiders.

Since you're making up words, you could follow any of the rules for a demonym. Wikipedia lists several suffixes that you could use: https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demonym

When making up words like this, just use what sounds best.

Comment: Actually, the name of the company is Black Square. I think, too, that "Black Squarer" sounds odd - I'm not a native speaker though. What would you suggest is the best way to denote that I belong to this company? Maybe another demonym? Googler for Google is fine, but Black Squarer for Black Square? Hmm...

Comment: @zoftvare: I would say Black Square employee.  I don't think you need to make it two words.

Answer (score 0):

You might try the suffix [*-ite*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/-ite):

> 1) a native, inhabitant, or citizen of"   ⇒ *Brooklynite*"
>   2) a descendant from or offspring of"   ⇒ *Israelite*"

though again the possibility of actual usage will depend on what you are tacking it onto.

Comment: "I'm a Black Squareite."  Somehow that just doesn't sound right.

Comment: @zondo I wasn't implying it would work with the specific example, but for future reference on name suffixes this might be useful.

Comment: I don't think it works for an employee of a company.  An employee is neither an inhabitant nor a descendant.